# Join a list with an entity and get the average from the second table

Tags: linq

I need to join a list with an entity and get the average of the matching records from the entity. Here is the list and entity

[image]

each student will have more than one score value in the second table and I need average score of each student.

Comment: What is your language? What is your DB? And what have you tried so far? Do you have a code to share with us?

Answer (score 1):

You can use GroupJoin extension method. It will Join the collections on StudentId and group the result by StudentId.

**GroupJoin** is an extension method. It groups one collection of objects by a key and joins those groups with another collection of keyed objects. With this method, we create a collection where, at each key, a group of results is placed.

```
        var students = new List<Student>
        {

            new Student { StudentID = 100, Name= "aaa", Address="Add1" },
            new Student { StudentID = 101, Name= "bbb", Address="Add2" },
            new Student { StudentID = 102, Name= "ccc", Address="Add3" },
            new Student { StudentID = 103, Name= "ddd", Address="Add4" },
        };
        var scores = new List<Score>
        {
            new Score { StudentID = 100, Marks = 70 },
            new Score { StudentID = 100, Marks = 60 },
            new Score { StudentID = 100, Marks = 80 },
            new Score { StudentID = 101, Marks = 50 },
            new Score { StudentID = 101, Marks = 40 },
            new Score { StudentID = 101, Marks = 70 },
            new Score { StudentID = 102, Marks = 74 },
            new Score { StudentID = 102, Marks = 77 },
            new Score { StudentID = 102, Marks = 75 },
            new Score { StudentID = 103, Marks = 76 },
            new Score { StudentID = 103, Marks = 80 },
            new Score { StudentID = 103, Marks = 70 },
            new Score { StudentID = 103, Marks = 60 },
        };

        var result = students.GroupJoin(scores,  
                            student => student.StudentID, 
                            score => score.StudentID,     
                            (std, groupedScore) => new 
                            {
                                StudentID = std.StudentID,
                                Name = std.Name,
                                Address = std.Address,
                                AvgScore = groupedScore.Average(x => x.Marks),
                            }).ToList();
```